# Is there a way to link a VPN (tun0) adapter to a fake physical (ethX) adapter?

Tags: networking, vpn

Is there a way to link a VPN (tun0) adapter to a fake physical (let's say ethX) adapter?

Comment: What do you mean by "link" an adapter to another?

Comment: And for that matter what do you mean by "fake physical adapter?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a bridge interface.  Lots of howto's for that exist (depending on if you want to do it with OpenVPN, /etc/network/interfaces, etc)